# Can't send SMS from J2ME using JAD+JAR

Tags: java-me, sms, ovi, ovistore

I have posted an application that send scheduled SMSs to OVI store ,but QA reject the application claiming that the application can't send any SMSs and it works fine when launching the application only with the .jar file.
Any Ideas how can I solve the problem.

Comment: Send them a mail for full details on the error you application is having .. post it here then we can help

Answer (score 0):

All I wanted to do is to declare one more permission in order to obtain the permission to send SMS when the application is signed:

javax.wireless.messaging.sms.send